# jQuery:how to use if in click function

Tags: jquery

I want to use if in click function.these are my codes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#circle").click(function () {
        if ($('#conent').css('display') == 'none') {
            window.open('http://www.google.com');
        }
    });
});
```

it doesn't work.it works without if.but i need if.

http://jsfiddle.net/mr_seven/ddrLf/

help me please,
thanks

Comment: typo #conent instead of #content, http://jsfiddle.net/ddrLf/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, its `content` instead of `conent`

```
$("#circle").click(function () {
    if ($('#content').css('display') == 'none') {
        window.open('http://www.google.com');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QGFSq/)

Comment: Thanks mate.I should be careful about this things.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled your selector  ?

```
$('#content')
```

Demo `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/ddrLf/6/